# Unable to create Group (no write intent on file)

Tags: python, h5py

I got this error everytime I load my model back from an HDF5 file. Below is my error trace.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda3New\Datasets\train.py", line 63, in <module>
    model = load_model(args["model"])
  File "D:\Anaconda3New\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 419, in
load_model
    model = _deserialize_model(f, custom_objects, compile)
  File "D:\Anaconda3New\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 249, in
_deserialize_model
    layer_weights = model_weights_group[name]
  File "D:\Anaconda3New\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\io_utils.py", line 303, in
 __getitem__
    val = H5Dict(self.data.create_group(attr))
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\h5py\_hl\gro
up.py", line 68, in create_group
    gid = h5g.create(self.id, name, lcpl=lcpl, gcpl=gcpl)
  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py\h5g.pyx", line 161, in h5py.h5g.create
ValueError: Unable to create group (no write intent on file)
```

I have read the below question but seems this is a different problem from what I have been through right now.

[I can't read data back in using h5py. "unable to create group"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15192874/i-cant-read-data-back-in-using-h5py-unable-to-create-group)

Because I am just loading my architecture and weights from my saved HDF5 file (created after pressing ctrl+c in cmd), how can I assign a mode to this HDF5 file?

Can anybody help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: What language are you using? The code you have doesn't look like h5py. To test HDF5 access by h5py, try opening your file with `h5py.File(filename,'r')` to test read access. Replace with `'w'` to test write access.

Comment: @kcw78 I am using python and have already set my model file as read like this: h5py.File(epoch_20.hdf5, 'r'). But I can't figure out why this error is coming. Please help.

Comment: You don't have write access if you open with 'r' mode. You need to use an append mode. There are 2 methods: 'r+' is Read/Write, file must exist; OR 'a' is Read/Write if file exists, create otherwise.

Comment: @kcw78 Thank you so much for helping me. The problem with my code was my model file (which I use to load my architecture and weights from) was set to only read mode ('r') and I didn't figure it out previously which led to this unimpeccable situation. Again, thank you so much for helping me.

Answer (score 2):

See there are two ways of saving a model. A:-

`model.save("Model_name.model")`
and B:-

```
model_json = model.to_json()
with open(file_name + ".json", "w") as json_file:
        json_file.write(model_json)
model.save_weights(file_name + '.h5')
```

I believe you were saving the model using the first method and it does not work because of many internal clashes. I recommend that you save the model using second way and then try to reload the model. It will work.

Another possible error might be that since you are saying the model is saved after pressing ctrl + c which is usually used to terminate program and hence it may result in improper saving of file. Try some different key combo.

Answer (score 0):

Give write permissions to h5py package before saving your file.

This should work : `h5py.get_config().default_file_mode = "w"`